# Data fetch from a dropdown in one page to other dropdowns to a new page and other problems

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So far you have been more than helpful in all my newbie questions, and I really appreciate it! Moving to my next problem...

I have a page (see photo below), where on the left, I have a tree with circuits. These circuits have an edit page like the photo, so when I change a value in the edit of a circuit, then it's stored in the database. Imagine having 100 circuits where you have to go to each one and change their settings.

[image: Tree with Circuits]

I also have second page with a table (see photo below), where I have summarized only the important settings. In that table, I am trying to fetch the data from page 1 to second page.

[image: Important Settings]

The problem is that most of the dropdowns in page 1 are dependable from another dropdown, so I am trying to create the same dropdowns in the second page inside the data table, where I will have the same dependable dropdowns. These are saved in the database, for sure, but I want when I change a value in page 2 to update page 1 and vice versa.

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

This page has something similar, but its impossible for me to implement, as I am new at this and I don't even really know where to put the JavaScript code.

https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/#examples
Example #6

```
<?php

    include ('./config/config.php');
    include ('./config/settings.php');
    include ('./controller/scripts/checklogin.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Circuits` WHERE `id`=".$_REQUEST['db'];
    $sqltype='select';
    include ('./controller/scripts/query.php');
    $db=$records;

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Cables` WHERE `id`=".$db[0]['Cables_id'];
    $sqltype='select';
    include ('./controller/scripts/query.php');
    $cable=$records;
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `MCBs` WHERE `id`=".$db[0]['MCBs_id'];
    $sqltype='select';
    include ('./controller/scripts/query.php');
    $mcb=$records;
        
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Meletes` WHERE `id`=".$_REQUEST['study'];
    $sqltype='select';
    include ('./controller/scripts/query.php');
    $study=$records;

//<---->    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Meletes` WHERE `id`=".$tmpvalues[0]['Study'];
    $sqltype='select';
    include './controller/scripts/query.php';
    $study=$records;

    $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `Circuits` WHERE `Meletes_id`=".$tmpvalues[0]['Study'];
    $sqltype='select';
    include './controller/scripts/query.php';
    $Dbs=$records;
    $Db = $Dbs[0]['id'];
    
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM `Circuits` WHERE `Symbol`=8 AND `Tree` like '%-".$Dbs[0]['id']."-%'";
    //echo $sql;
        //$sql="SELECT Calc1 FROM `DBOrder` WHERE CID=".$db[0]['id'];
    $sqltype='select';
    include ('./controller/scripts/query.php');
    $solar=$records;

// echo $tmpvalues[0]['Study'];
?>
    <style>
      #study-output img {
        width: 90px;
      }
    </style>
<body class="">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <header class="main-header">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <a href="index.php?workflow=home" class="logo">
                    <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
                    <span class="logo-mini"><b>E</b>C</span>
                    <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
                    <span class="logo-lg"><b>EL</b>Culator</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                  <?php include './blocks/navbar.php'; ?>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
            <aside class="main-sidebar el-sidebar-color">
                <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                <section class="sidebar">
                    <?php include './blocks/sitebar.php'; ?>
                </section>
                <!-- /.sidebar -->
            </aside>

            <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
            <div class="el-right-sid content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

            <section class="content-header">
                <h1>
                  Elculator
                  <small>Edit Circuits </small>
                </h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="/index.php"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./index.php?workflow=studies"><?php echo "Studies";?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="./index.php?workflow=study&id=<?php echo $tmpvalues[0]['Study'];?>&page=db"><?php echo $study[0]['Name'];?></a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href=""><?php echo "Edit Circuits"; ?></a></li>
                </ol>

<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 2px;
}

table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

table trr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

table th {
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #FF5733;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h4 style="text-decoration: underline; font-weight:bold"> EDIT CIRCUITS </h4>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>

  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
    <th>LOAD (KW)</th>
    <th>LOAD (A)</th>
    <th>VOLT</th>
    <th>MCB</th>
    <th>(A)</th>
    <th>POLES</th>
    <th>(KA)</th>
    <th>RCD</th>
    <th>RCD TYPE</th>
    <th>CABLE TYPE</th>
    <th>REF. METHOD</th>
    <th>INST. METHOD</th>
    <th>PH+N CSA</th>
    <th>CPC CSA</th>
    <th>LENGTH</th>
    <th>V.DROP</th>
    <th></th>
 
 </tr>


<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['BRBLGR']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['Name']; ?>" size="40"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['Load']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['IDF']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['Phase']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>
<td>

<form>
  <select>
    <option>-- Select --</option>
    <?php
        $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT MCBs_id From Circuits");  // Use select query here 

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $formdata['MCBs_id'] ."'>" .$formdata['MCBs_id'] ."</option>"; 
        }   
    ?>  
  </select>
</form>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['MCBs_id']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['MCBsRatingZS_id']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>


<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['poles']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['IscMCB']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['Rcd']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['RcdType']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['Cables_id']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['ReferenceMethod']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['InstallationMethod']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['Csa']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['Cpc']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['Length']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['VD']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

        <td>
            <span class="table-remove">
              <button type="button" mdbBtn color="danger" rounded="true" size="sm" class="my-0" (click)="remove(id)">Delete</button>
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</table>

</style>
</head>



<br>

            </section><!-- /.content -->
            </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
            <?php include './blocks/footer.php'; ?>

        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container-fluid -->

        <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
        <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->
        <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/dist/js/ajax.js"></script>
        <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/dist/js/context-menu.js"></script>
        <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/dist/js/drag-drop-folder-tree.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/dist/js/Chart.js"></script> -->
        <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/dist/js/custom.js"></script>

        <!-- FastClick -->
        <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- AdminLTE App -->
        <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/dist/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- ChartJS 1.0.1 -->
        <!-- <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/plugins/chartjs/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
        <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
        <script src="./template/<?php echo $template;?>/dist/js/pages/dashboard2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

send parameters from current page to Next page using Get method > as per parameter run function on PHP page

$parameter= $_GET['parameter'];

```
    switch ($favcolor) {
```

case "red":
function red()
break;
case "blue":
blue();
break;

}

Comment: can you please send me an example from my code?

Comment: <td>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo  $formdata[0]['MCBs_id']; ?>" size="2"/>
</td>

Answer (score 1):

make few functions, those function prints different type Dropdown list > use function as per URL parameter example : `https://IndiaOneway.com/index.php?index=0&id=8569` **HERE you can see index and *`id`* is parameter, can be stored on after reaching `index` page using `$ID=   $_GET['id'] ;` *// `$id` value will be `8569`***

Comment: Yes thanks but each circuit has its own id and the problem i see is that every new circuit changes id, so each row in the data table has to GET each id individually. Will this work in bidirectional way? when change value in new page the value will replace values in page 1?

Comment: you send  2,048 in URL like https://bangalorecalltaxi.com/id1=23&id2=85 and so on another technique  create array of textboxes select them by ID/NAME using JS > send data using AJAX / LocalStorage